# Bash, adding together the results of a grep

Tags: bash, shell, grep

In bash I want to echo some integer value which is the sum of various "grep | wc -l" combinations.

I have tried

```
echo $( (`grep string file.txt | wc-l`) + (`grep string2 file.txt | wc -l`))
```

I assumed the return of these greps is just an integer bash would recognise but it doesn't.  Where do I need to explicit and why?

Comment: try ``echo $((`grep string file.txt | wc -l`  + `grep string2 file.txt | wc -l`))`` .. changed `( (` to `((`, `) + (` to `+` and `wc-l` to `wc -l`

Comment: @cc6g11, `$( )` doesn't create an arithmetic context; `$(( ))` does that, hence Sundeep's comment above. `$( )` is the modern (superior) alternative to backticks for command substitution.

Comment: The parenthesis around the back tics are suspect

Comment: @dawg, they'd be valid if `$(( ))` were used on the outside, since `$(( (4) + (6) ))` is valid.

Comment: @cc6g11, that said, why two separate `grep`s? `grep -E 'string|string2' file.txt` will get you all your lines with either string in one pass.

Comment: And of course one can just run `wc` once with the combined result as its input, even if that isn't acceptable: `{ grep string file.txt; grep string2 file.txt; } | wc -l` -- that way there's no addition needed at all.

Comment: Just do `awk '/string1/{c++} /string2/{c++} END{print c+0}' file.txt` instead of multiple greps, pipes, wcs, etc.

Comment: @EdMorton: Good point. Added to my answer.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy : `grep -E 'string|string2' file.txt` will have a different (maybe better) count when both strings appear on the same line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simplifying your inner commands (with `seq` to produce lines) but keeping your same parenthesis, this does not work:

```
$ echo $( (`seq 5 | wc -l`) + (`seq 10 | wc -l`))
-bash: command substitution: line 1: syntax error near unexpected token `+'
-bash: command substitution: line 1: ` (`seq 5 | wc -l`) + (`seq 10 | wc -l`)'
```

[Arithmetic Expansion](https://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/arithexp.html) in Bash is two parenthesis next to each other:

```
$ echo $(( 1+2 ))
3
```

This works:

```
$ echo $((`seq 5 | wc -l` + `seq 10 | wc -l`))
15
```

As does the more modern version:

```
$ echo $(( $(seq 5 | wc -l) + $(seq 10 | wc -l) ))
15
```

So your parenthesis are not matched and spaced incorrectly.

---

As a side note, if you can refactor the two `grep` to produce one output with something like:

```
$ grep "string 1|string2" | wc -l
```

As Charles Duffy suggests, with [command grouping](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Command-Grouping.html) either in a sub shell or same shell you can combine two greps output in a single stream. Then you do not need the `echo` or the arithmetic.

Using `seq` as a simple model for the lines from two different processes, you can do:

```
$ (seq 10; seq 5) | wc -l     # sub shell
      15
$ { seq 5; seq 10; } | wc -l  # same shell
      15
```

---

Finally, to the extent you have the "*sum of various "grep | wc -l" combinations*" you might consider `awk` as better `grep` + `wc` replacement.

You can do:

```
awk '/string1/{c++} /string2/{c++} END{print c+0}' file.txt
```

as well as far more complex combinations than you should be doing in Bash alone. It will perform much better if you have many different search strings.

Comment: Why add two `wc`s' output at all, vs funneling both input commands into just one `wc`? Do that and you don't even need the command substitution or the `echo`.

Comment: I thought his question was why his use of arithmetic context was not working with two subprocesses and trying to answer THAT vs rewriting his actual use to be better -- also a reasonable answer.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy: I added that suggestion to my answer. As always, thanks for your sage Bashisms!

Comment: There's also `grep -c` that does the same as `grep | wc -l`.

Comment: Use the additional `next` in `awk '/string1/{c++;next} /string2/{c++} END{print c+0}' file.txt` when you want the same result as `grep -c "string 1|string2" file.txt`